# How do I fix ie 6 hover?

Tags: html, menu, drop-down-menu, hover

This is my code for my menu:

```
/*Menu*/    
#menu {
    text-align: right;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
    font-size: 0.75em;
}

#menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 5px 5px 5px;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: normal;
    border: 0px solid #03426A;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    background: #F3F4FF;
    position:relative;
    width: auto;
    float:right;
}
#menu ul li {
  float: left;
}
#menu li ul {
    display: none;
}
#menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;  
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 15px 5px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: normal;
    border: none;
}
#menu ul li a:hover {
    color: #0A67A3; 
}
#menu li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
#menu li:hover li {
  float: none;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
#menu li:hover a { color: #0A67A3; }
#menu li:hover li a:hover { color: #000; }

/*End Menu*/
```

I have tried 2 tutorials however have not found a way of making the menu work in ie 5.5 or 6. How can I fix this?

Comment: Copy your html also... 
Nevermind, answer is down..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE 5.5? Really... Wow I feel sorry for you if you need to still be compatible that far...Legacy corporate app I suppose? Damn!!

IE6 only understands `:hover` for `<a>` elements that's for sure. But you can try the solution given here that uses a htc file to create a new css behavior: http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html

Comment: wow, that trick actually works in ie 5.5!! Thanks, it doesn't look great on older browsers but at least they can navigate properly now!

Answer (score 3):

IE6 doesn't support :hover pseudoclass on elements other than anchor tags.  Son of Suckerfish has a solution that may work for you: http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/

Comment: hmm.. I still can't get this to work. Where do I put the javascript code?